# Kubtunu 18.04 clear Port 43

Tags: kubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I need to be able to use Port 43 on my Kubuntu 18.04. Unfortunately it seems to be blocked by the OS itself. Anyone can help me out how to free this port?

Comment: What have you tried to do to free the port? Can you [edit] your question to include the debug processes you've taken so far? Please see [ask] and take our [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux/Unix/Ubuntu port numbers below 1024 require root privileges to be assigned to a process.

So execute your program with `sudo` for elevated privileges and it should  function as desired.